# expected gauge in metric process_start_time_seconds label Prometheus

Tags: windows, monitoring, grafana, prometheus

I have a scenario where I need to monitor some windows machine running in different locations.
Constraints:
`Those systems do not have static public IP`

I have installed `wmi_exporter` on windows machine running on port `9182`. On the Linux(AWS) server I have installed   `Prometheus` and `Pushgateway`.

I have a registered job running on windows machine which basically Invoke-WebRequest to `http://localhost:9182/metrics` and get the content and then send them to push gateway URL `http://pushgateway_server.com:9091/metrics/job/{job_name}/instance/{machine-name}`

I can see the received data at `http://pushgateway_server.com:9091` but when I open  `http://pushgateway_server.com:9091/metrics` It gives following error.

```
An error has occurred:

expected gauge in metric process_start_time_seconds label:<name:"instance" value:"" > label:<name:"job" value:"some_jop" > counter:<value:1.569916592e+09 >
```

I am unable to identify the problem. Is it possible to monitor the machines in given scenario? Am I using right tools?

How can I solve the given issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're pushing some metric as a counter, after having previously pushed it as a gauge. You should go into your PushGateway and manually delete all existing metrics (or do it via HTTP API requests). And then make sure that all your instances are configured the same and one doesn't push some metric as a gauge while another pushes the exact same metric as a counter.